# Google API to list users in directory

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth, google-admin-sdk

I am developing a user page to allow managers to create users by selecting a new user from a drop down list. I will like to populate the drop down with company users from Google directory. So this user page will only be accessible after login.

As I read, [Google Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/overview) accesses private user data and needs access token to work. I will like to use this Google directory API [users.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list) method to retrieve users from Google directory. I have a look at the example from [quick start for javascript](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/js). The issue is this script requires the user to login again, and this would confuse the admin users.

On the login page, I use the google the HTML sign-in button to render Login page, returning the JWT token to our webapp's login endpoint. The returned token credential contains login user's email profile but no access token.

Could someone please advise how to modify below on so that I can retrieve users on the user page.

```
async function initializeGapiClient() { await gapi.client.init({
          apiKey: API_KEY,
          discoveryDocs: [DISCOVERY_DOC],
        });
       await listUsers(); 
} 

async function listUsers() {
        let response; try {
          const request = {
            'customer': 'my_customer',
            'maxResults': 10,
            'orderBy': 'email',
          };
          response = await gapi.client.directory.users.list(request);
        } catch (err) {
          document.getElementById('content').innerText = err.message;
          return;
        }

        const users = response.result.users; 


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue you are having is that you are using JavaScript.  Client side JavaScript does not have the ability to store login information for future use. Which means that every time your users return they will need to login and authorize your application again.

I would suggest that you switch to a server sided language which will allow your users to login and for you to store a refresh token for them enabling you to request a new access token when ever you need to.  node.js for example would work as well.

Remember though only users who have admin access on your workspace account are going to be able to do this the user will need to have access

## Node.js Quickstart

The following is a quick example for node.js, its for an installed app but will show you how things need to be put together for refreshing your access token.

```
// npm install googleapis@105 @google-cloud/local-auth@2.1.0 --save
// npm install googleapis

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const process = require('process');
const {authenticate} = require('@google-cloud/local-auth');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly'];

// Token File Name
const TOKEN_FILE = 'token.json'

// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), TOKEN_FILE);
const CREDENTIALS_PATH = 'C:\\Development\\FreeLance\\GoogleSamples\\Credentials\\Workspace-Installed-TestEverything.json';
// the workspace customer id found in admin on Google Workspace
const WORKSPACE_CUSTOMER_ID = '[REDACTED]'

/**
 * Reads previously authorized credentials from the save file.
 *
 * @return {Promise<OAuth2Client|null>}
 */
async function loadSavedCredentialsIfExist() {
    try {
        const content = fs.readFileSync(TOKEN_PATH,{encoding:'utf8', flag:'r'});
        const credentials = JSON.parse(content);
        return google.auth.fromJSON(credentials);
    } catch (err) {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Serializes credentials to a file compatible with GoogleAUth.fromJSON.
 *
 * @param {OAuth2Client} client
 * @return {Promise<void>}
 */
async function saveCredentials(client) {

    const content = fs.readFileSync(CREDENTIALS_PATH, {encoding:'utf8', flag:'r'});
    const keys = JSON.parse(content);

    const key = keys.installed || keys.web;
    const payload = JSON.stringify({
        type: 'authorized_user',
        client_id: key.client_id,
        client_secret: key.client_secret,
        refresh_token: client.credentials.refresh_token,
    });
    await fs.writeFileSync(TOKEN_PATH, payload);
}

/**
 * Load or request or authorization to call APIs.
 *
 */
async function authorize() {
    let client = await loadSavedCredentialsIfExist();
    if (client) {
        return client;
    }
    client = await authenticate({
        scopes: SCOPES,
        keyfilePath: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
    });
    if (client.credentials) {
        await saveCredentials(client);
    }
    return client;
}

/**
 * Lists the names and IDs of up to ten users on Google Workspace.
 * @param {OAuth2Client} authClient An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
async function listUsers(authClient) {
    const service = google.admin({version: 'directory_v1', auth: authClient});
    const res = await service.users.list({
        customer: WORKSPACE_CUSTOMER_ID,
        pageSize: 10,
        fields: 'nextPageToken, users(id, name)',
    });

    const users = res.data.users;
    if (users.length === 0) {
        console.log('No users found.');
        return;
    }

    console.log('users:');
    users.map((user) => {
        console.log(`${user.name.fullName} (${user.id})`);
    });
}

authorize().then(listUsers).catch(console.error);
```

## Google workspace

In google workspace under the user, You can check if they have admin access.

[image]

Comment: Can you please show the content in Workspace-Installed-TestEverything.json

Comment: No this is my credentials.json file downloaded from google developer console.   [how to create credentials.json](https://youtu.be/qwqJcyLQSSQ)

Comment: How did you tell that was a client side Javascript? As Node.js is also writen in Javascript.

Comment: Becouse you tagged the Question [tag:JavaScript]. I assumed that you knew what language you were using if you had been using service sided JavaScript (IE: Node.js) you would surly have used [tag:NodeJs].  Welcome to stack proper tagging of your question is how those of us who attempt to help you know exactly what you are doing.  [ask]

Comment: **JavaScript is a simple programming language that can be used with any browser that has the JavaScript Engine installed. Node. js, on the other hand, is an interpreter or execution environment for the JavaScript programming language**  #JustSaying

Comment: Would https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ be useful to find out if the user has the admin access to our workspace? where about I could grant admin access to the user.

Comment: Dont bother with PlayGround its just for testing you already have working code.   Go to google workspace account you can grant someone admin access there.

Comment: would the authenticate method used in the node.js you provided (in the authorize function) popup the Google login page? if yes, how do I configure the UX-mode etc? How do I get Google to post the JWT token to my endpoint?

Comment: how do I verify when I am not getting result from Listusers is due to users not having admin access or something wrong with the code. How do I verify I am granted the admin access when the sys admin said so

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251110/discussion-between-hannah-and-daimto).

Comment: The UX is on googles authorization server,  you cant configure that.    The token is returned to the redirect uri you configure in google developer console.    Its not Node but its curl this may help you [understanding Oauth2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBC_tVJIx5w)   I can see you have a lot of questions maybe open a few new ones.  Someone with more Node.js knowlage then me may be able to help you more.

Comment: Thanks for the video you posted and it certainly deserves a like! I will try the code using your blog post https://www.daimto.com/how-to-get-a-google-access-token-with-curl/ and video.

Comment: For those who might be interested there are more google-Auth for node.js here https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/google-auth-library/latest

Comment: note: service account credentials need to be created on google developer console by an account on your domain and then the domain admin has to configure domain wide deligation.  The code for use with a service account is different than the code shown above.   service accounts are used for server to server authentication not for authorizing a user.